# Windows phone 8.1 BLE device connect/disconnect

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating a Windows phone 8.1 application which uses Bluetooth Low Energy feature(BLE). I need to discover all the near by BLE devices in my app and connect discovered devices. But I couldn't find any source to achieve this. I only found the code to scan the paired devices. In ios and android it is possible to scan, connect / disconnect through code. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it could help, but I think this guy has reach it with Windows IoT.

http://blog.falafel.com/arduino-btle-gatt-bracelet-and-windows-iot-core/

Maybe this could help to start making your own BLE stack for Windows Phone 8.1.